# Understanding android app permissions section (Android Nougat)

Tags: permissions, 7.1-nougat

In android Nougat, using an android phone if you go to settings>installed apps>[name of app]>permissions

There are three sections there: Details, App Permissions, and other permissions.

What are the differences between these three sections? Why are they arranged in this way?

In details section there are detail explanation about a list of Notes Permission regarding Security, Privacy and Other. Are these permissions listed in the details section activated or not? Why are they different (or arrange in a different way) from the one listed in the app permissions sections for the same app?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 6.0(API level 23), app permissions are listed as *normal permission* and *dangerous permission*

> Depending on how sensitive the area is, the system may grant the permission automatically, or it may ask the user to approve the request.

The section **App Permissions** tells you about the [Permission Groups](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups), which are dangerous permissions requested by app and can be revoked by user.

> All dangerous Android system permissions belong to permission groups.

The section **All Permissions** provides you more details regarding permissions. In which permissions are listed as:
**Permission Group** for all dangerous permissions further followed by requested permissions in that group.
Permissions which are automatically granted by system are listed under **Other app capabilities**.
[image: screenshot]

Since you are running Android N, if [targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) of any particular app is 23 or higher,

1. All the permissions listed under Other app capabilities are granted.
2. If you have granted permission for a particular group like **Storage**, then further permissions listed under storage are automatically granted. App will not ask again if permission is granted.
3. If targetSdkVersion of app is less than 23, then it will not ask for permission at runtime. However you may revoke any dangerous permission from that app.

Comment: Is it possible to change which of these permissions appear in a given Permission Group? For example, I really don't like that Android automatically grants the "run at startup" permission automatically. On my device, I want Android to explicitly get my approval for an app to be able to "run at startup"..